# How can TensorFlow/Keras's default tmp directory be changed?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, keras

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. According to https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/:

> The default directory where all Keras data is stored is:
>
> $HOME/.keras/
>
> In case Keras cannot create the above directory (e.g. due to
> permission issues), /tmp/.keras/ is used as a backup.

In my case, Keras lacks permissions for $HOME/.keras and can't write to /tmp/.keras due to a full hard drive. I would like to place Keras's tmp directory in a custom location on a different hard drive. How is this best accomplished?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can change the default behavior. Using `$HOME` or `/tmp/.keras` is [hardcoded](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fcc4b966f1265f466e82617020af93670141b009/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L234).

Comment: Changing line 234 of python/keras/utils/data_utils.py to the indicated directory works. Thanks @jakub!